Loop through all possible values of a field in VBA Access
I have a recordset in which the TaxCode column can take a dozen different values. I would like to calculate, for each TaxCode value, the sum of TaxableAmount field, without knowing in advance which TaxCode values I have.



TaxCode
TaxableAmount




22
100


22
150


63
250


22
60



From this example, I would like to obtain these totals:



TaxCode
TaxableAmount




22
310


63
250



How can I do it?
I've tried with
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TaxCode, TaxableAmount FROM dbo_MA_SaleDocDetail WHERE SaleDocID = " & SaleDocId)
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF
    For Each Field In .Fields
     if...?
Loop

Thank you so much.

Yes, I could use a query, but in this case I have to calculate it through VBA because then I need the Totals to update some fields in my form.

You can combine queries and VBA. If you specifically need to calculate this in VBA, you should explain a bit more why calculating it in a query then retrieving those results and working with them in VBA doesn't answer your question.

This is something you should really do in SQL, not in VBA. It's one of the most simple grouped aggregate queries:
SELECT TaxCode, SUM(TaxableAmount)
FROM dbo_MA_SaleDocDetail 
GROUP BY TaxCode

And you can combine that with your VBA:
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TaxCode, SUM(TaxableAmount) FROM dbo_MA_SaleDocDetail WHERE SaleDocID = " & SaleDocId & " GROUP BY TaxCode")

Though you should really use parameterized queries

You calculate that in the query:
set rs = "SELECT TaxCode, SUM(TaxableAmount) " & _ 
         "FROM dbo_MA_SaleDocDetail WHERE SaleDocID = " & _  
          SaleDocId & " GROUP BY TaxCode"

